# No Picker Data from Json in bundle - SWIFTUI

Tags: swiftui, picker

I have a country json in my bundle. I can properly decode the json because as shown in the attached picture I'm getting the proper count and the list is working. But the `Picker` isn't being populated with the countryNames.

The countries are formatted like this:

```
{
    "id": "001",
    "countryName": "United States",
    "countryCode": "US"
},
{
    "id": "002",
    "countryName": "Canada",
    "countryCode": "CA"
},
{
    "id": "003",
    "countryName": "Mexico",
    "countryCode": "MX"
},
```

My struct for the JSON:

```
struct CountryData: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    var id: String
    var countryName: String
    var countryCode: String
}
```

My Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var plateCountrySelection: String = "1"
    
    let vm  = Bundle.main.decodeJson(
        [CountryData].self,fileName: "CountryCodes.json")
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text( "\(vm.count)")
            Picker(
                selection: $plateCountrySelection,
                label: Text("Enter Country"),
                content: {
                    ForEach(vm, id: \.self) { item in
                        Text(item.countryName).tag(item)
                    }
                })
                }
        List {
            ForEach(vm) { item in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(item.countryName)
                        .font(.headline)
                    Text(item.countryCode)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gMY0.jpg)

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: Is `CountryCodes.json` included in your target? Is it in the correct format? What happens if `decodeJson` fails? Have you used the debugger to step through it?

Comment: Change `let vm` to `@State var vm` and set the `id` to the `count`. `Picker(...){...}.id(vm.count)`

Comment: Unrelated  but `id: \.self` is nonsensical if the model conforms to `Identifiable`. Remove the `id` parameter. And be aware that the `tag` of the picker must be the same type as the `selection`.

Comment: `plateCountrySelection` should be initially set to `"001"` and respectively `.tag(item.id)`

Comment: @jnpdx, It's definitely decoding. The Text( "\(vm.count)") gives me the correct number of entries, plus the "List {  ForEach(vm)" part shows the proper data.

Comment: What happens when you embed everything in a NavigationView?

Comment: @jnpdx, that works, very strange behavior. Thanks.

Comment: Not strange at all — it needs a navigation view to “navigate” to the next screen